# kill background process called by a function in loop

Tags: bash

I need to batch process some files, so I wrote a bash script that defines a function to process those files with an external package, and I ran the function in a loop for each file. Since there're way too many files, I let the function run in background.

An conceptual example is as following. The main script is called test.sh:

```
test () {

./toy.sh $1

}

for (( i=1; i<=10; i++))
do
  test $i &
done
```

And toy.sh is as following (just an example, in real life it's doing some data processing):

```
for (( i=1; i<=10; i++))
do
  echo $1
  sleep 3
done
```

Question: is there a way to kill the test function (which calls toy.sh) running in the background while looping? What is the best coding habit of putting process in background?

Comment: `killall toy.sh`?

Comment: `$!` contains the PID of the last background process. You can assign this to a variable, then later `kill $var`.

Comment: `killall toy.sh` doesn't do the work... and weirdly $! gives nothing; the output is simply empty.

Comment: Forgot to add this: in real life I have a list of directories to process in the loop, and in each directory there're a few hundred files. Each function call for those files takes about half a minute, then within `test()` it automatically moves to the next file. Therefore the PIDs are always changing every half minute.

Comment: I hope in real script the function is not named `test` because it conflicts with conditional `test` utility. If you are not getting any values from `$!` your script is not written correctly.